# news :: RealURL Path for MetaTag og:url for detailpage

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I want to render the meta tag og:url for a detailpage of a news item. I have the following TS:

```
page.headerData.2999 {
    wrap = <meta property="og:url" content="{$extglobal.domain}|" />
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        typolink {
            parameter.data = TSFE:id
            returnLast = url
        }
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        stdWrap.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[news]=|
        required = 1
    }
}
```

But the url in the og:url metag tag is rendered as:

https://example.com/news/detailpage/&tx_news_pi1[news]=1671

Any ideas how to achieve the full realUrl path for og:url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found a solution to make my TS working:

```
    page.headerData.1038 >
page.headerData.2999 = COA
page.headerData.2999 {
    wrap = <meta property="og:url" content="{$extglobal.domain}|" />
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        typolink {
            parameter.data = TSFE:id
            additionalParams {
                data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
                rawUrlEncode = 1
                wrap = &tx_news_pi1[news]=|
            }
            useCacheHash = 1
            returnLast = url
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the additional URL parameters to the `typolink` part, either with `additionalParams` (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Functions/Typolink.html#additionalparams) or `addQueryString` (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Functions/Typolink.html#addquerystring). With `additionalParams` you can set your own parameters to add. With `addQueryString` you can add the parameters of the current URL to the URL.

However the `news` extension supports Open Graph meta tags by default. More on how to configure it can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/Index.html#opengraph